# Filtering keys in hashmap in rust

Tags: rust

I am not able to figure out why I am not getting keys filtered properly any hints

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("Hello", "World");
    h.insert("Aloha", "Wilkom");
    let dummy = h.keys().filter(|x| x.contains("Aloha"));
    println!("{:?}", dummy);
}
```

Output shows both the keys. I would expect only the key that matched

```
Filter { iter: ["Hello", "Aloha"] }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an artifact of the `Debug` impl for filter's return value. If you collect the keys into a `Vec` it works as expected:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut h:HashMap<&str,&str> = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("Hello","World");
    h.insert("Aloha","Wilkom");
    let dummy: Vec<_> = h.keys().filter(|x| x.contains("Aloha")).collect();
    println!("{:?}",dummy);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fcba23913f730a0a243c0aa8511253f2))

If you directly print out `Filter`, you get:

```
Filter { iter: ["Aloha", "Hello"] }
```

which technically is correct: `dummy` is a filter based on the iterator `["Aloha", "Hello"]`